# Dynamic menu from codeigniter library folder can't be return

Tags: php, codeigniter

I create a dynamic menu in the folder of library in codeigniter framwork.

```
class Left_menu {

private $ci; 

function __construct()
{
    $this->ci =& get_instance();    // get a reference to CodeIgniter.
}

function get_company () 
    {
         $html_out = '';

         $company = $this->ci->db->query("select * from perusahaan");

         $html_out  .= "<ul class='sub_list'>";

         foreach ($company->result() as $row)
            {
                $id = $row->id; 
                $name = $row->name; 
                $location = $row->location;
                    $html_out .= "<a href='".site_url("perusahaan_controller/detailPersahaan/".$id."")."'>";
                    $html_out .= "<li>".$name."</li>";
                    $html_out .= "</a>";
            }

         $html_out  .= "</ul>";

         $html = $html_out;
         //print_r ($html); 

         return $html;

    }

 }
```

And the in the view I call it:

```
<?php $this->left_menu->get_company(); ?>
```

However, it doesn't show the menu at all. It does if only I print it, `//print_r ($html);` , and the weird is it printed the menu as how I want to return it. (It looks like it turns the `return` function into print_r).

Comment: You need to `<?php echo $this->left_menu->get_company(); ?>`

Comment: I agree with @machineaddict. You need to `echo` your result

Comment: Another case of failure to simply [read the documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create a library for this.

Simply use a Model to fetch the data and inject your sidebar into your current controller.

You can do this by creating a partial view called sidebar, and pass it some data from the model, then insert it into your current view.

### Controller

```
class Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('mymodel');

        $data = $this->MyModel->get_data();

        // call the sidebar view and pass it some data from model
        // at this point the view is in the buffer so it can be manipulated before final output.
        $sidebar = $this->load->view('sidebar', array(
            'data'  =>  $data
        ), true);

        return $this->load->view('index', array(
            'sidebar'  =>  $sidebar
        ));        
    }
}
```

### Model

```
class MyModel extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function get_data()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('perusahaan');

        return ( $query->num_rows() > 0 ) ? $query->result() : false;
    }
}
```

### views/sidebar

```
<ul class="sublist">
    <?php foreach($data as $_data): ?>
        <li id="<?php echo $_data->id;?>">
            <a href="<?php echo ".site_url('perusahaan_controller/detailPersahaan/')."/".$_data->id.""><?php echo xss_clean($_data->name);?></a>
        </li>
    <?php foreach; ?>
</ul>
```

### views/index

```
<aside class="sidebar">
    <?php echo $sidebar; ?>
</aside>

<div>
    //... content
</div>
```

Comment: One more question, what if I put the file sidebar in one folder named template, while the index view is out of the folder? how to echo it?

Comment: sure just place it in a subfolder of your views folder `$this->load->view('template/sidebar') // This will grab from views/template/sidebar.php`